# Change users password after the first log in

Tags: html, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm working on a mobile application using ionic2 and I want the users to change their password if it was the first time they login to the application and I was planning to create new field in the Database call ChangePassword and check it value then direct the user to change the password but my question is their another way to do for example a code in that can be typed in the  application

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack overflow, please take a look at [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). For now it is hard to help you as we don't know anything about your data structure neither what you want to change and where. Also note that punctuation is your friend ;-).

Comment: Is there another way? tell us what is the way you tried, what are the problems with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want users to change the password after first login, you can add a column in database for active users, and try to give the condition as if an user is not active, then lead him to ChangePassword page, otherwise to Home page.